# Deskew scanned images

Tags: c#, image-manipulation

I am working in OMR project and we are using C#.  When we come to scan the answer sheets, the images are skewed.  How can we deskew them?

Answer (score 9):

VB.Net Code for this is available [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/graphics/Deskew_an_Image.aspx), however since you asked for C# here is a C# translation of their Deskew class (note: Binarize (strictly not necessary, but works much better) and Rotate are exercises left to the user).

```
 public class Deskew
 {
        // Representation of a line in the image.  
        private class HougLine
        {
            // Count of points in the line.
            public int Count;
            // Index in Matrix.
            public int Index;
            // The line is represented as all x,y that solve y*cos(alpha)-x*sin(alpha)=d
            public double Alpha;
        }


        // The Bitmap
        Bitmap _internalBmp;

        // The range of angles to search for lines
        const double ALPHA_START = -20;
        const double ALPHA_STEP = 0.2;
        const int STEPS = 40 * 5;
        const double STEP = 1;

        // Precalculation of sin and cos.
        double[] _sinA;
        double[] _cosA;

        // Range of d
        double _min;


        int _count;
        // Count of points that fit in a line.
        int[] _hMatrix;

        public Bitmap DeskewImage(Bitmap image, int type, int binarizeThreshold)
        {
            Size oldSize = image.Size;

            _internalBmp = BitmapFunctions.Resize(image, new Size(1000, 1000), true, image.PixelFormat);
            Binarize(_internalBmp, binarizeThreshold);


            return Rotate(image, GetSkewAngle());
        }

        // Calculate the skew angle of the image cBmp.
        private double GetSkewAngle()
        {
            // Hough Transformation
            Calc();

            // Top 20 of the detected lines in the image.
            HougLine[] hl = GetTop(20);

            // Average angle of the lines
            double sum = 0;
            int count = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i <= 19; i++)
            {
                sum += hl[i].Alpha;
                count += 1;
            }
            return sum / count;
        }

        // Calculate the Count lines in the image with most points.
        private HougLine[] GetTop(int count)
        {
            HougLine[] hl = new HougLine[count];

            for (int i = 0; i <= count - 1; i++)
            {
                hl[i] = new HougLine();
            }
            for (int i = 0; i <= _hMatrix.Length - 1; i++)
            {
                if (_hMatrix[i] > hl[count - 1].Count)
                {
                    hl[count - 1].Count = _hMatrix[i];
                    hl[count - 1].Index = i;
                    int j = count - 1;
                    while (j > 0 && hl[j].Count > hl[j - 1].Count)
                    {
                        HougLine tmp = hl[j];
                        hl[j] = hl[j - 1];
                        hl[j - 1] = tmp;
                        j -= 1;
                    }
                }
            }

            for (int i = 0; i <= count - 1; i++)
            {
                int dIndex = hl[i].Index / STEPS;
                int alphaIndex = hl[i].Index - dIndex * STEPS;
                hl[i].Alpha = GetAlpha(alphaIndex);
                //hl[i].D = dIndex + _min;
            }

            return hl;
        }


        // Hough Transforamtion:
        private void Calc()
        {
            int hMin = _internalBmp.Height / 4;
            int hMax = _internalBmp.Height * 3 / 4;

            Init();
            for (int y = hMin; y <= hMax; y++)
            {
                for (int x = 1; x <= _internalBmp.Width - 2; x++)
                {
                    // Only lower edges are considered.
                    if (IsBlack(x, y))
                    {
                        if (!IsBlack(x, y + 1))
                        {
                            Calc(x, y);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        // Calculate all lines through the point (x,y).
        private void Calc(int x, int y)
        {
            int alpha;

            for (alpha = 0; alpha <= STEPS - 1; alpha++)
            {
                double d = y * _cosA[alpha] - x * _sinA[alpha];
                int calculatedIndex = (int)CalcDIndex(d);
                int index = calculatedIndex * STEPS + alpha;
                try
                {
                    _hMatrix[index] += 1;
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
                }
            }
        }
        private double CalcDIndex(double d)
        {
            return Convert.ToInt32(d - _min);
        }
        private bool IsBlack(int x, int y)
        {
            Color c = _internalBmp.GetPixel(x, y);
            double luminance = (c.R * 0.299) + (c.G * 0.587) + (c.B * 0.114);
            return luminance < 140;
        }

        private void Init()
        {
            // Precalculation of sin and cos.
            _cosA = new double[STEPS];
            _sinA = new double[STEPS];

            for (int i = 0; i < STEPS; i++)
            {
                double angle = GetAlpha(i) * Math.PI / 180.0;
                _sinA[i] = Math.Sin(angle);
                _cosA[i] = Math.Cos(angle);
            }

            // Range of d:            
            _min = -_internalBmp.Width;
            _count = (int)(2 * (_internalBmp.Width + _internalBmp.Height) / STEP);
            _hMatrix = new int[_count * STEPS];


        }

        private static double GetAlpha(int index)
        {
            return ALPHA_START + index * ALPHA_STEP;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Scanned document are always skewed for an average [-10;+10] degrees angle.
It's easy to deskew them using the Hough transform, like Lou Franco said. This transform detects lines on your image for several angles. You just have to select the corresponding one to your document horizontal lines, then rotate it.

1. try to isolate the pixel corresponding to your document horizontal lines (for instance, black pixels that have a white pixel at their bottom).
2. Run Hough transform. Do not forget to use 'unsafe' mode in C# to fasten the process of your whole image by using a pointor.
3. Rotate your document in the opposite angle found.

Works like a charm on binary documents (easily extendable to grey level ones)

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer: I work at [Atalasoft](http://www.atalasoft.com), [DotImage Document Imaging](http://www.atalasoft.com/products/dotimage) can do this with a couple of lines of code.

Deskew is a term of art that describes what you are trying to do. As Ben Voigt said, it's technically rotation, not skew -- however, you will find algorithms under automatic deskew if you search.

The normal way to do this is to do a [hough transform to look for the prevalent lines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hough_transform) in the image. With normal documents, many of them will be orthogonal to the sides of the paper.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure it's "skew" rather than "rotation" (rotation preserves angles, skew doesn't).

- Use some sort of registration mark (in at least two places) which you can recognize even when rotated.
- Find the coordinates of these marks and calculate the rotation angle.
- Apply a rotation transformation matrix to the image.